# Repeated error while running Face Recognition vs code

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, face-recognition, deepface

I am new to Deep Learning and my first Project is FACIAL EMOTION RECOGINISTION
I am trying to use this DeepFace library but seems kind of stuck at the moment can anyone help ?

```
import cv2
from cv2 import cvtColor
from deepface import DeepFace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('Images\happy\happy_001.jpg')

# plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
# plt.show()

predictions = DeepFace.analyze(img, actions = ['age', 'gender', 'race', 'emotion'])
```

and the error i am getting is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\OneDrive - Graphic Era University\Desktop\ML AND AI\FACE RECOG\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    predictions=DeepFace.analyze(img, actions = ['age', 'gender', 'race', 'emotion'])
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\deepface\DeepFace.py", line 355, in analyze
    models['gender'] = build_model('Gender')
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\deepface\DeepFace.py", line 61, in build_model
    model = model()
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\deepface\extendedmodels\Gender.py", line 49, in loadModel
    gender_model.load_weights(home+'/.deepface/weights/gender_model_weights.h5')
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 507, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr=swmr)
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 220, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 106, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (truncated file: eof = 232972459, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 537149760)
```

I certainly don't know how to solve this .. can anyone help?

**I am using VS CODE with python 3.9.6**

Comment: It looks like ypu've got an OS file reading arror, right? Check if your picture file is good and accessible.

Comment: yes @Bohdan my file is good but idk why i am getting error again and again been stuck here for half a day

Answer (score 0):

Check that file: "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 106, in h5py.h5f.open. I guess your issue rises from there. Try to re-install the libs. Also, here your problem was discussed and, probably, solved:  https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6221